# Inner border for table cells only

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to add a table border for just the inner sections, I don't want the borders to be placed at the first and last cell.

[image]

So, I tried:

```
 .grid > div:last-of-type {
      border-right: none;
 }
```

However, as you can see in the image, the last cell is 5px larger than the rest now, that is because it is trying to fill the empty space left behind when we removed the padding from it... How can I remove the padding, but keep its height the same as the others? maybe a way to make all of them stretch to fit? please bare in mind, I can't add a fixed height as the number of cells will change and their hight may vary.

I have also tried adding `border-collapse:collapse;` it stretched them (AWESOME!) but the middle cell is now slightly smaller than the other two.

Here is a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ju76y/5/
(Added images to the fiddle)

```
.grid {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: green;
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
   word-wrap: break-word;

   text-align: center;
   letter-spacing: 0px;
   word-spacing: 0px;
}

   .grid > div {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: top;
      border-right: 5px solid red;
   }

   .grid > div:last-of-type {
      border-right: none;
   }
```

Comment: Set up a fiddle? you are lacking some `css` code here, per your comment to the below answer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ju76y/

Comment: @Leo check my tricky answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the cell property:

`box-sizing:border-box;`

Comment: Already applied that:    box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: I have it in the reset.css - sorry

Answer (score 0):

This will align the last div to align properly with others

```
.grid > div:last-child > div {
   margin-top: -2px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ju76y/6/show/)**

same need to be applied for the first child also

```
.grid > div:first-child > div {
   margin-top: -2px;
}
```

Comment: Same mate :/ didn't fix it :(

Comment: Did you check the demo, I see the last div is of same height as the middle one. I don't see difference in heights now

Comment: They are note, try and resize